# How I find that string contain a character more then 6 time in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I want to implement an alogorithm/validation. How can I find out if a string contains a specific character more than 6 times in Flex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways, I can think of:

1. Use [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) and [.replace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) like this:

   ```
   var ch:String = "a";    //Character, that must be checked
   var text:String = "This is an example to show how many times '"+ch+"' occured.";
   //Matches non-`ch` characters
   var regexp:RegExp = new RegExp("[^"+ch+"]","g");   
   //Replacing non-`ch` characters with empty string
   var timesOccured:Number = text.replace(regexp,"").length;  
   trace(text, ": " ,timesOccured );
   ```
2. Use [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) and [.match()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match%28%29) like this:

   ```
   var ch:String = "a";    //Character, that must be checked
   var text:String = "This is an example to show how many times '"+ch+"' occured.";
   //Matches `ch` characters
   var regexp:RegExp = new RegExp(ch,"g");
   var matches:Array = text.match(regexp);
   var timesOccured:Number = 0;
   //`matches` can be 'null', so we are performing additional check
   if( matches ){   
       timesOccured = matches.length;
   }
   trace(text, ": " ,timesOccured );
   ```

Now when you have `timesOccured`, you could easily do your validation:

```
if( timesOccured > 6 ){
   //Do some stuff
}else{
   //Do other stuff
}
```

**Warning:** If your `ch` is a special character for Regular Expression, like a `.`,`+`,`(`,`]`,`\`,etc..., you need to *escape* it, before passing it to `regexp` variable:

```
ch = ch.replace(new RegExp("[.*+?|()\\[\\]{}\\\\]", "g"), "\\$&");
```

Comment: @ Engineer - But one problem still not solve this solution calculate all matches but in the string but i want to find like this 111111122 or 2333333344 but ignore like 333343333333.

Comment: @TahirAlvi You didn't mentioned about it in your question. How could I know about such specifity ??!!! But in that case, you can check whether your string is sorted, and when it is, then apply my suggested method.However it will be good, that you ask a different question in SO. Try maximally be specific,when you are asking a question. We can't read your mind ).

Comment: Ok Thank You - Actually i post question with word repeating Characters but the  ashiaka change my question wording.

Comment: I post in a separate question and here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193426/how-i-find-that-string-contain-a-repeating-character-more-then-6-time-in-flex

Answer (score 2):

a simpler alternative to regular expressions can be the following:

```
var str:String = "This is an example to show how many...";
//find occurrences for character 'a'

trace("Ocurrences:" + str.split('a').length-1);
```

Comment: Great way to do it, hadn't thought of it myself. Definitely seems better than @Engineer's. +1 from me