# Flex (ActionScript 3): How to find that a string contain a repeating character more than 6 times?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

How I find that string contains a repeating character more than 6 times in Flex?
In my case, the user input is only digits (0-9) and I am doing for US Fax no validation.

```
like 11111112255, 225555555522, etc
```

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression way:

```
/(.)\1{6}/
```

This will search for *any* character (not necessarily digit) repeated 7 times.

```
/(\d)\1{6}/
```

The same, but for digits only.

There are techniques that will be generally faster than regexp, for example, slightly modified [Bitap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap_algorithm) algorithm may prove to be faster.

Here's an altered version of Bitup algorithm to search for repeating characters in a string:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class BitapConsequent extends Sprite
    {
        public function BitapConsequent()
        {
            super();
            test();
        }

        private function test():void
        {
            // 10 -1 3 0
            trace(bitapConsequent("---####$$$^^^^^^", 6),
                bitapConsequent("---####$$$^^^^^^", 7),
                bitapConsequent("---####$$$^^^^^^", 4),
                bitapConsequent("---####$$$^^^^^^", 3));
        }

        private static function bitapConsequent(
            text:String, consequent:uint):int
        {
            // Unless found, the result is negative
            var result:int = -1;
            var len:int = text.length;
            var offset:int;
            var reverse:int;

            if (len >= consequent)
            {
                consequent--;
                len -= consequent;
                // loop through the whole string sans
                // the substring which is shorter than
                // the number of characters that have to
                // be the same
                outer: for (; offset < len; offset++)
                {
                    // jump to the farmost end of the possible
                    // match and walk back checking that each
                    // two characters match, i.e. if this is
                    // the array of characters a = ['a', 'b', 'b']
                    // then first check if a[2] == a[1], then
                    // if a[1] == a[0], if characters are equal,
                    // continue to the next iteration, else--
                    // restart the search
                    for (reverse = offset + consequent;
                        reverse > offset; reverse--)
                    {
                        if (text.charAt(reverse) !== 
                            text.charAt(reverse - 1))
                            continue outer;
                    }
                    // If we got here, we've found `consequent'
                    // equal characters, so terminate the loop
                    result = offset;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The earlier version indeed used bitup algorithm, but after some thought, I've realized it wasn't required, so this is a bit more refined version, which also doesn't limit one to the 32-characters matches only.

Comment: ok, so something like: "for each digit, match if the next 6 are the same"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
var testString:String = "1111111";
if ( testString.search( /[0-9]{7}/ ) != -1 )
    trace( "The string '" + testString + "' contains more than 6 repeating digits" );
```

**Edit:**

As @wvxvw points out, this will break if your string is something like `1112222` or `1234567` - his regex gets around that

Comment: Check out http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - the community tab on the right for more examples

Comment: In my case i always amount like that 1112222 or 1234567, Please provide me exact regExp for that type of Amount.

Comment: @Tahir: take the regex provided by wvxvw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193426/how-i-find-that-string-contain-a-repeating-character-more-then-6-time-in-flex/13193887#answer-13195321 - `/(\d)\1{6}/`

Answer (score 0):

I do this in this way,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(id_input.text.length >=10)
            {
                for(var i:uint=0; i<4; i++)
                {
                    var counter:int = 0;
                    var str:String = id_input.text.substr(i,1);
                    var index:uint = 0;
                    index = i;
                    index += 1;
                    //case 1
                    if(str == id_input.text.substr(index ,1))
                        counter ++;
                    index += 1;
                    //case 2
                    if(str == id_input.text.substr(index ,1))
                        counter ++;
                    index += 1;
                    //case 3
                    if(str == id_input.text.substr(index ,1))
                        counter ++;
                    index += 1;
                    //case 4
                    if(str == id_input.text.substr(index ,1))
                        counter ++;
                    index += 1;
                    //case 5
                    if(str == id_input.text.substr(index ,1))
                        counter ++;
                    index += 1;
                    //case 6
                    if(str == id_input.text.substr(index ,1))
                        counter ++;
                    if(counter >= 6){
                        Alert.show('More then 6 char present in string');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">

    <s:TextInput id="id_input"/>
    <s:Button label="Validate" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />

</s:VGroup>
```